# Notification is not being sticky with Notifee

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, notifications, foreground-service

I'm currently working on a React Native application and using the notifee library to manage notifications. My requirement is straightforward: I want to display a notification that is 'sticky', meaning the user shouldn't be able to swipe it away.

I've followed the library documentation with several properties under the android configuration. However, the notification isn't acting as expected; it's not being sticky.

Here's what I've done so far:
In My component:

```
  async function onDisplayNotification() {
    await notifee.requestPermission();

    // Create a channel (required for Android)
    let channelId;
    try {
      channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
        id: 'locations',
        name: 'Location Channel',
        importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
        visibility: AndroidVisibility.Public,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to create Channel');
    }

    const settings = await notifee.getNotificationSettings();

    // Display a notification
    try {
      await notifee.displayNotification({
        title: 'Notification Title',
        body: 'Main body content of the notification',
        android: {
          channelId,
          sticky: true,
          ongoing: true,
          smallIcon: 'ic_launcher', // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
          // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
          // pressAction: {
          //   id: 'default',
          // },
          autoCancel: false,
          asForegroundService: true,
          color: AndroidColor.RED,
          actions: [
            {
              title: 'Stop',
              pressAction: {
                id: 'stop',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to display notification');
    }
  }
```

In index.js
I've registered a foreground service as follows:

```
notifee.registerForegroundService((notification) => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
      if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id === 'stop') {
        notifee.stopForegroundService();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

- The notification appears correctly.
- I've confirmed that the channel (locations) is created successfully.

Despite these, the notification is not sticky. When I swipe, it goes away, which isn't the intended behavior.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide some insight into what might be going wrong? Any guidance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Android has changed this behavior in newer versions of Android.
"If your app shows non-dismissable foreground notifications to users, Android 14 has changed the behavior to allow users to dismiss such notifications."

Please see below post for detail update.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all